# Prompt for SQL Server to connect to in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project that current uses a hard coded SQL connection string. I want to make this more flexible so that when I move it to another environment the user can browse for the SQL server to connect to since it will have a different than my test server. I have tried countless ways to Google for a solution and I am just not getting any hit. I am looking for something similar to the open file dialog in VB, except for SQL servers, where it will list all the servers available on the network and let the users select one, then enter credentials.

Does such a thing exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy to develop a dialog box similar to one SQL Server Management Studio uses.  Be aware that all instances on the network cannot be enumerated because broadcast packets are not typically routed and due to firewalls so you'll need to allow the user to enter a server name in the combobox.  Here's a code snippet to return a DataTable of the found instances (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources
```

Below is a screenshot of the login dialog from SSMS.  Just populate the server name combobox with the server and instance names from the data table, and add the other needed controls.

[image]